# Приходят пустые сообщения с формы в телеграм

Tags: php, html, form, telegram

Суть проблемы: с формы отправляется заявка в телеграм, но доходит с пустой информацией. Как это можно исправить или в чем проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<form action="php/sendform.php" method="POST" class="modal__form">
  <input type="text" name="order_name" class="order__input" id="order_name" placeholder="Ваше имя: *" >
  <input type="tel" name="order_phone" class="order__input" id="order_phone" placeholder="Контактный телефон: *">
  <input type="text" name="order_city" class="order__input" id="order_city" placeholder="Ваш город: *">
  <div class="form__checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
    <label for="checkbox">Я согласен с </label><a href="./privacy-policy.pdf" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="order__submit" id="order_submit" value="Оставить заявку" disabled="disabled">
</form>

<?php

$name = $_POST['order_name'];// Берём данные из input c атрибутом name="name"
$phone = $_POST['order_phone']; // Берём данные из input c атрибутом name="phone"
$city = $_POST['order_city']; // Берём данные из input c атрибутом name="city"

$token = "тут токен мой";
$chat_id = "тут ид мой";
$sitename = "тут сайт"; //Указываем название сайта

$arr = array(
  'Заявка с сайта: ' => $sitename,
  'Имя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
  'Город:' => $city
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

if ($sendToTelegram) {
  header('Location: ../pages/thx.php');
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
так она пустой и будет) попробуйте так

<?
    if ($_POST) {
        $name = $_POST['order_name'];// Берём данные из input c атрибутом name="name"
        $phone = $_POST['order_phone']; // Берём данные из input c атрибутом name="phone"
        $city = $_POST['order_city']; // Берём данные из input c атрибутом name="city"
        $token = "тут токен мой";
        $chat_id = "тут ид мой";
        $sitename = "тут сайт"; //Указываем название сайта
        $arr = array(
            'Заявка с сайта: ' => $sitename,
            'Имя: ' => $name,
            'Телефон: ' => $phone,
            'Город:' => $city
        );
        foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
            $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
        };
        message_to_telegram($txt);
    }
    function message_to_telegram($text) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array(
            $ch,
            array(
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $token . '/sendMessage',
                CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                    'chat_id' => $chat_id,
                    'text' => $text,
                ),
            )
        );
        curl_exec($ch);
    }
    ?>
```